# Does nginx free allows multiple proxy_cache_valid?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to cache with this:

```
proxy_cache_valid 200 4h;
proxy_cache_valid 404 401 1m;
```

But nignx seems to just ignore the second entry. Is it because I'm not using nginx plus?

Comment: This works fine. You have some other problem. Post the output of `nginx -T`.

Answer (score 2):

##### Does nginx free allows multiple proxy_cache_valid?

#### The Answer is: Yes it does.